# How does a PackedScene work when passed in an exported variable

Tags: godot, gdscript

To my beginner understanding, in order to use a scene saved on the drive, one must first use `ResourceLoader.load()` to load the scene to acquire a `PackedScene`, then instantiate it using `PackedScene.instance()` to acquire the `Node` that can be finally added as a child.

Following this principle, one can easily export a script `String` variable and use it to set which scene will be loaded by a node - even with convenient hints like this:

```
export(String, FILE, "*.tscn") var scene_path
```

But that's not fully descriptive in my opinion. I want to select a scene - an only scene - in that exported variable. Looking around the internet, this [Godot Q&A post](https://godotengine.org/qa/42320/export-nodepath-variable-to-a-external-scene) mentions one can export a `PackedScene` variable like any other to link to another scene. So I immediately thought of this:

```
export(PackedScene) var new_scene = null
```

This looks much cleaner - especially the ability to initialize it to `null`, as well as having access to methods like `can_instance()` to catch any accidental false inputs in the editor... however, this looks like there is one important link of the chain I mentioned at the start missing. In the end, I'm still selecting the `PackedScene` as a path on disk, so when does the `load()` happen?

Is this a valid and correct use of the `export` keyword, or could this come back to haunt me later if I overuse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly valid use of `export` and `PackedScene`. In fact, you can do this with any `Resource` (please notice you use a *`ResourceLoader`* not a "SceneLoader"). The `Resource` type has support for serialization and deserialización out of the box.

*See [When and how to avoid using nodes for everything](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/best_practices/node_alternatives.html).*

---

When the game starts it has to load (and instance) the main scene. When you change the scene to another scene, Godot has to load (and instance) that another scene. Or when you tell Godot to load a `PackedScene`, Godot has to load that scene.

To tell Godot to load a `PackedScene` you can use `preload` (loads on parse), `ResourceLoader.load`, `load` (simplified `ResourceLoader.load`), or `ResourceLoader.load_interactive` (loads in stages to avoid blocking the game while loading large resources, each stage load a subresource).

And if the `PackedScene` that is being loaded happens to have nodes that export some `Resource` (such as `PackedScene`), those has to be loaded alongside too.

*That is when the load of the `PackedScene` happens. I hope that makes sence.*

---

Furthermore, this is not only for `PackedScene`. You can export any other `Resource` type, for example `export(Shape)` works.

---

Aside, I also want to mention that the editor support for exporting custom resources is not great. If you do `export(CustomResource)` where `CustomResource` is a `Resource` type you created, it won't work. Instead you are forced to do `export(Resource)`, which results in the editor showing all possible `Resource` types under the sun for you to select.

Workaround:

```
tool
# …

export(Resource) var variable:Resource setget set_variable
func set_variable(new_value:Resource) -> void:
    if !(new_value is CustomResource): new_value = CustomResource.new()
    variable = new_value
```

See the proposal [Add first-class custom resource support](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/18).

Comment: I'm re-reading this again on the next day and I noticed one thing - you said _"And if the `PackedScene` that is being loaded happens to have nodes that export some `Resource` (such as `PackedScene`), those has to be loaded alongside too."_ - that raises a question: Imagine I have a scene that features 10+ buttons to load individual levels. All these buttons have an exported `PackedScene` variable. Does that mean upon loading the scene with the buttons, Godot loads all the level scenes too? Is there a way to prevent that, other than using exported `String`s along with the `load()` method?

Comment: @MartyCagas Yes, they load. I should mention that if you have the same `PackedScene` in multiple places it only loads once. You can use the Profiler and Monitor panels to see how much of an impact that has. Also, below the `PackedScene` there will be a "Bundled" option where you can see what loads with it, and you will find `PackedScene`s  with their own "Bundled" there. For having control of what to load, using the path is the best way. But there is something else you can do: If those buttons are scenes, you can use "Load As Placeholder" on them, which gives you `InstancePlaceholder`s.